# EntitySQL 'IN subquery

Tags: subquery, entity-sql

I have the following T-SQL:

`SELECT Cust.[CompanyName] 
FROM Customers AS Cust
WHERE
(
  Cust.[CompanyName] IN (SELECT CustSQ1.[CompanyName] AS [Customer Company name] 
FROM Customers AS CustSQ1
WHERE
(
  CustSQ1.Country = 'Argentina' )
) )`

How do I do the same in EntitySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Corresponding EntitySQL is:
`"SELECT Cust.[CompanyName] FROM (SELECT CustSQ1.[CompanyName] FROM Customers AS CustSQ1 WHERE ( CustSQ1.Country = 'Argentina' )) AS Cust"`